# Unique value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having a data frame as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,1,1,2,2,3],'l1':['a','a','b','c','c','b'],'l2':['b','d','d','f','e','f']})
df
```

I want to select unique values of l1,related to c

```
for i in set(df.c):
    week_list=df.groupby(df['c']==i)['l1'].unique()

    print(i,week_list)
```

Expected output:

```
1 [a,b]
2 [ c ]
3 [ b ]
```

please help me to find unique value using the above code?

Comment: `groupby + agg` should do: `df.l1.groupby(df.c).agg(set)`

Comment: Why is "c" in the expected output for 3?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.groupby('c').agg({'l1':'unique'})
```